# Renaming a file by adding characters using sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix

EX:

```
$ progaddtext file1 .txt<br>
```

should rename file1 to file1.txt

I found this code to successfully remove the text from the end of the first arg.

```
mv $1 $(echo $1 | sed "s/$2$//")
```

Just having a little trouble figuring out how to do the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv $1 $(echo $1 | sed "s/$/$2/")
```

Even though using mmv or rename would be much easier, and this question seems to lack a homework tag?

Comment: Ahh I see now. Also new to the website, added the HW tag and will if necessary on future posts.

Comment: and why `$1` instead of `"$1"`? Interested in failure if whitespace involved?

Comment: @glglgl: Probably keeping unnecessary complexity out of the homework. Just as I said, in any production context one would just use mmv and be happy, whitespace or not.

Comment: yeah were allowed to use mmv now, much easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `$1` as `file1` and `$2` as `.txt` why not just do:

```
mv "$1" "$1$2"
```

Comment: I wish but I have to do it using sed.

Comment: and why `$1` instead of `"$1"`? Interested in failure if whitespace involved?

Comment: @glglgl More because I always forget my quoting. Thanks for the reminder folks.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
mv $1 $(echo $1 | sed -e "s/$/.txt/")
```

Comment: and why `$1` instead of `"$1"`? Interested in failure if whitespace involved?

Comment: Missed the part where he stated his file had a whitespace.
Trololololo?